# Is this version of the site real, or a phishing scam?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

While searching around google, I found the following site:

[Potentially Fake Site! (Doesn't load on mobiles)](http://statsstackexchange.booksmedia.net/questions/140362/how-to-fit-a-stochastic-matrix-to-given-data)

I almost logged in to it using my google account, then noticed the bizarre URL.

Is this a real SE site? It looks identical as far as I can tell to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Edit:

All the random questions on the right all appear to link to other fake sites. Like this for example:

http://fitnessstackexchange.computer-electronics.net/questions/25660/breathing-during-running

Except " fitnessstackexchange.computer-electronics" probably looks illegitimate enough for more people to catch on. It looks like a big site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That kind of site is called a "SCRAPER."  It's great that you brought it to our attention.  It is spoofing the entirety of SE, not just stats.  (I investigated using a browser in a virtual machine.)  The recommended response is described in two answers to the meta SO post [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers).  Briefly,

> Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the form on the contact us page, linked at the bottom of every page.
>
> Use the "Other" reason on the form (fortunately, we don't get enough of these reports to justify making SCRAPERs their own category/reason). Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

and

> If you see a scraper URL outranking the original source of content in Google, please tell us about it: http://bit.ly/scraperspamreport

I haven't seen the latter, so I haven't reported to Google, but I did contact the SE team with this info.

### Update

I have received these messages from the SE team and want to reproduce them here because their thanks really apply to the OP and everyone else reading this thread and helping out.

#### Message 1

> Thank you for reporting this content. I've passed the information along to the person at our company who handles such issues. It's the diligence of users like you that helps us stay valuable!
>
> Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're working on it.

#### Message 2

> I checked with our network engineers and they blocked the IP that was proxying our sites. Anything they haven't cached already will show a CloudFlare error.
>
> Thanks for the report,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was something like that. I've seen sites scrape SE before, but they don't do a full blown spoof as well; they just steal the q&a. And, FYI, this did in fact outrank all other sites in a google search; this was the top result.

Comment: Would you mind reporting it to Google, then?  They will want to know the exact search you used.

Comment: OK. Will do; if I can find it in my history.

Comment: That's awesome. It's good to see such a swift response from a website that I don't even pay (directly) to use! Thanks mod for helping this along.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a scam.  I notice that I have an account [there](http://statsstackexchange.booksmedia.net/users/7290/gung), but I've never seen that site before.  I wouldn't log in there.